# How does Windows 10 task manager detect a virtual machine?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, reverse-engineering, virtualization

The Windows 10 task manager (taskmgr.exe) knows if it is running on a physical or virtual machine.

If you look in the *Performance* tab you'll notice that the number of processors label either reads *Logical processors:* or *Virtual processors:*.

In addition, if running inside a virtual machine, there is also the label *Virtual machine: Yes*.

See the following two screen shots:

[image: taskmgr locical processors]

[image: taskmgr virtual processors]

My question is if there is a documented API call taskmgr is using to make this kind of detection?

I had a very short look at the disassembly and it seems that the detection code  is somehow related to [GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405488(v=vs.85).aspx) and/or [IsProcessorFeaturePresent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724482(v=vs.85).aspx) and/or [NtQuerySystemInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation).

However, I don't see how (at least not without spending some more hours of analyzing the assembly code).

And: This question is IMO not related to other existing questions like *How can I detect if my program is running inside a virtual machine?* since I did not see any code trying to compare smbios table strings or cpu vendor strings with existing known strings typical for hypervisors ("qemu", "virtualbox", "vmware"). I'm not ruling out that a lower level API implementation does that but I don't see this kind of code in taskmgr.exe.

<strike>Update: I can also rule out that taskmgr.exe is using the [CPUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX=1:_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) instruction (with EAX=1 and checking the *hypervisor* bit 31 in ECX) to detect a matrix.</strike>

Update: A closer look at the disassembly showed that there is indeed a check for bit 31, just not done that obviously.

I'll answer this question myself below.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't think so. At least I did not see any hints in the code that it tries to match smbios table data, or vendor strings with known virtualization strings (qemu, vmware, ...)

Comment: Taskmgr uses CPUID in a function **__int64 WdcMemoryMonitor::CheckVirtualStatus()** to check the status.

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes and no. `CheckVirtualStatus()` uses CPUID for several detection tasks (e.g. signature, manufacturer  ID string) but only once with EAX=1 and in that case only bit 5 of ECX  is analyzed in order to check for the VMX extension. And a missing VMX flag is not a suitable indicator for a virtual machine.

Comment: ok, I only took a short look with IDA and haven't checked wat the EAX values means

Comment: @magicandre1981 nevertheless you were right. I've missed it because I've concentrated on the eax bit shifts and did not notice that the first use of CPUID in that function was followed by a jns of test ecx,ecx which is the same as testing bit 31 ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've analyzed the x64 taskmgr.exe from Windows 10 1803 (OS Build 17134.165) by tracing back the writes to the memory location that is consulted at the point where the *Virtual machine: Yes* label is set.

Responsible for that variable's value is the return code of the function `WdcMemoryMonitor::CheckVirtualStatus`

Here is the disassembly of the first use of the `cpuid` instruction in this function:

```
lea     eax, [rdi+1]                 // results in eax set to 1
cpuid
mov     dword ptr [rbp+var_2C], ebx  // save CPUID feature bits for later use
test    ecx, ecx
jns     short loc_7FF61E3892DA       // negative value check equals check for bit 31
...
return 1
loc_7FF61E3892DA:
// different feature detection code if hypervisor bit is not set
```

So taskmgr is not using any hardware strings, mac addresses or some other sophisticated technologies but simply checks if the *hypervisor* bit ([CPUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX=1:_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits) leaf 0x01 ECX bit 31)) is set.

The result is bogus of course since e.g. adding `-hypervisor` to qemu's cpu parameter disables the hypervisor cpuid flag which results in task manager not showing *Virtual machine: yes* anymore.

And finally here is some example code (tested on Windows and Linux) that perfectly mimics Windows task manager's test:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <intrin.h>
#else
#include <cpuid.h>
#endif

int isHypervisor(void)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    int cpuinfo[4];
    __cpuid(cpuinfo, 1);
    if (cpuinfo[2] >> 31 & 1)
        return 1;
#else
    unsigned int eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
    __get_cpuid (1, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx);
    if (ecx >> 31 & 1)
        return 1;
#endif
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (isHypervisor())
        printf("Virtual machine: yes\n");
    else
        printf("Virtual machine: no\n"); /* actually "maybe */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Here is a documentation from VMWare describing the leaf 0x01 ECX bit 31: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1009458 - exactly how you have found out.

Comment: I wonder if this value can be found/read from the WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) repository. I looked around and didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of KVM/QEMU (answer from /r/VFIO)

If you use feature policy disable for the hypervisor it will get rid of that message in taskmgr. In the xml like so

```
<cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none'>
<topology sockets='1' cores='6' threads='2'/>
<feature policy='disable' name='hypervisor'/>
</cpu>
```

Or add `-cpu …,-hypervisor` to your cli.